# Core Data delete rule -- to-many relationship, delete when empty

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm a little fuzzy on how the delete rules for relationships in Core Data work, at least beyond the simple cases described in the documentation.

Most of those cases, and most of the answers I've seen for questions here, use a model where the object on left side of a one-to-many relationship "owns" the objects on the right side: e.g. a `Person` has `PhoneNumber`s, and if you delete the person you delete all their associated numbers. In that kind of case, the solution is clear: Core Data will handle everything for you if you set the relationships like so:

```
Person      --(cascade)-->> PhoneNumber
PhoneNumber --(nullify)-->  Person
```

What I'm interested in is the opposite: A to-many relationship where the "ownership" is reversed. For example, I might extend the CoreDataBooks sample code to add an `Author` entity for collecting all info about a unique author in one place. A `Book` has one author, but an author has many books... but we don't care about authors for whom we don't list books. Thus, deleting an `Author` whose `books` relationship is non-empty should not be allowed, and deleting the last `Book` referencing a particular `Author` should delete that `Author`.

I can imagine a couple of ways to do this manually... what I'm not sure of is:

- does Core Data have a way to do at least some of this automagically, as with relationship delete rules?
- is there a "canonical", preferred way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could override `prepareForDeletion` in your `Book` class and check if the author has any other books. If not you could delete the author.

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {
    Author *author = self.author;
    if (author.books.count == 1) { // only the book itself
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:author];
    }
}
```

Edit: To prevent deletion of an author with books you could override `validateForDelete` or even better: don't call deleteObject with an author with books in the first place

Comment: Unless there's something else going on, this seems to fail in the case where, say, both of an author's books are deleted at once. I'm printing out the value of author.books.count in my corresponding prepareForDeletion and it is 2 for both books. Then the author never gets deleted. (class names changed to match question but relationships are the same.)

Answer (score 2):

Rickstr,

Check below for the relationships to get your two criteria done.

1. > Author -- (Deny) -->> Books

deleting an Author whose books relationship is non-empty should not be allowed

> DENY: If there is at least one object at the relationship destination, then the source object cannot be deleted.

1. > Book -- (Cascade)-- > Author

deleting the last Book referencing a particular Author should delete that Author

You cannot delete the Author, as our first rule is saying, if there are any Books which are non-empty should not be deleted. If they are not present the Author gets deleted.

I think theoretically it should work. Let me know, if this works or not.

Comment: `Author -(Deny)->> Books` is good, but `Book -(Cascade)-> Author` causes authors to be deleted as soon as the first book by that author is deleted. (Either that or I'm doing something wrong.)

Comment: But the same Author is binded with the DENY relation right, So theoretically it wont be deleted, as he has another book.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Tim's solution, you can override the `willSave` method in your Author `NSManagedObject` subclass. Note that if you do use Tim's solution, I highly recommend filtering the books set for books that haven't been deleted; this way if you delete all of the Author's books at the same time, the Author will still be deleted.

```
- (void)willSave {
    if (!self.isDeleted) {
        NSPredicate *notDeletedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *bindings) {
            return ![(NSManagedObject *)evaluatedObject isDeleted];
        }];
        NSSet *filteredBooks = [self.books filteredSetUsingPredicate:notDeletedPredicate];
        if (filteredBooks.count == 0)
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
    }
    [super willSave];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

Set the deletion rule on the 'book' relationship of your author entity to 'Deny' meaning that as long as there is a book linked to your author it cannot be deleted.

Subclass your book entity and override the prepareForDeletion() function as follows:

```
public override func prepareForDeletion() {
    super.prepareForDeletion()
    do {
        try author.validateForDelete()
        managedObjectContext?.delete(author)
    } catch {}
}
```

Validate for delete will throw an error unless the book relationship is empty.
You can optionally handle the error.