# Deleting NSManagedObject subclass not nullifying it's many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm using CoreData with Swift and I have two entities. Let's call them `Item` and `Tag`. They're set up with a basic many-to-many (both have either items/tags which are optional, nullify,to-many) relationship and look similar to:

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
  // Rest of attributes
  @NSManaged var tags: NSSet
}
```

Setting the relationships up works fine, however when I try to delete an item:

```
managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait {
  managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item)
  managedObjectContext.save(/** it saves with no error */) 
}
```

It deletes the item object but any tags it has aren't being updated, if I fetch them elsewhere it still has item in items but will fail to fault obviously. (And the Z2TAGS table still shows the item id that was deleted).

I've tried manually updating the relationships myself before deleting but that doesn't change anything I have to save after updating relationships and then delete the object.

I'm sure that something is going wrong though, surely CoreData shouldn't be getting in this state with a basic many-to-many with the correct inverses set up? Is it something with Swift? Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In core data, apart from the type of relationship(one to one, many to many etc.), you can also set the delete rule. For example, if there is a relationship like this

A --->B  (one to one)

B --->> A (one to many)

You can set a delete rule i.e. what happens to the instances of B when A is deleted.

This post [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707971/core-data-delete-rule-to-many-relationship-delete-when-empty) talks about delete rules in detail.

Comment: Both relationships are "Nullify" though, so in the case of an Item being deleted it should remove the item from the Tag's items relationship surely?